# Subracting one list from another not working

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to do this for a while and I've tried things I've found on forums but it's still not working and I feel like it's a really obvious error. Here's my code:

```
allnum=[]
num=[]
for i in range(100):
    allnum.append(random.randint(1,99))

num.append(allnum[:10])
print (allnum)
print(num)

allnum= [i for i in allnum if i not in num]
print (allnum)
```

and the result is just:
`[55, 94, 88, 66, 34, 99, 76, 41, 48, 55, 84, 16, 57, 58, 46, 26, 10, 25, 10, 94, 93, 3, 29, 74, 6, 47, 45, 67, 1, 9, 10, 10, 3, 34, 13, 91, 81, 70, 87, 46, 26, 52, 28, 66, 88, 9, 30, 43, 85, 32, 38, 5, 60, 65, 27, 52, 68, 94, 94, 14, 46, 5, 8, 9, 32, 62, 6, 18, 84, 86, 2, 12, 97, 99, 84, 13, 64, 39, 84, 75, 23, 88, 21, 60, 37, 33, 75, 53, 88, 54, 28, 5, 29, 97, 38, 21, 27, 25, 17, 31]`

`[[55, 94, 88, 66, 34, 99, 76, 41, 48, 55]]`

`[55, 94, 88, 66, 34, 99, 76, 41, 48, 55, 84, 16, 57, 58, 46, 26, 10, 25, 10, 94, 93, 3, 29, 74, 6, 47, 45, 67, 1, 9, 10, 10, 3, 34, 13, 91, 81, 70, 87, 46, 26, 52, 28, 66, 88, 9, 30, 43, 85, 32, 38, 5, 60, 65, 27, 52, 68, 94, 94, 14, 46, 5, 8, 9, 32, 62, 6, 18, 84, 86, 2, 12, 97, 99, 84, 13, 64, 39, 84, 75, 23, 88, 21, 60, 37, 33, 75, 53, 88, 54, 28, 5, 29, 97, 38, 21, 27, 25, 17, 31]`

sorry if it's a really stupid mistake:)

Comment: `num.append(allnum[:10])` I believe should be `num=allnum[:10]`

Comment: @DyZ, as it is currently, it's a nested list, which isn't what s/he wants.

Comment: @ArthurDent You are right.

Comment: sorry, I accidentally did that on the question, it's not in my actual code

Comment: As a side note: If you have a collection that's primarily there to test for membership (`in`/`not in`), using a `set` instead of a `list` is conceptually clearer (set membership is a fundamental thing about sets), and also usually a lot faster (Python sets implement `in` in constant time instead of linear). Plus, sets have nice shortcuts like `intersection`/`&` that again make sense conceptually and also speed things up.

Comment: I didn't use a set because I wanted to change it later on in the code

Comment: You can change a set later, just as easily as a list. If the order of elements matters, or duplicate values matter, etc., those are good reasons not to use a set, but wanting to be able to change it isn't.

Comment: oh okay I didn't realise, sorry @abarnert

Comment: Also, even if you want to use a collection as a list, you may sometimes want to copy it to a set for some local operation. For example, the cost of making a temporary set of the elements of a list is linear; if that lets you turn a quadratic algorithm into a linear one, it's usually worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `num.append`, which takes one object as parameter and appends it to the list. So, you appended one element, which is a list containing ten integers (note the two opening and closing square brackets when you print `num`.

You wanted to use `extend`, which takes an iterable as argument, and adds each of its elements to the list:

```
num.extend(allnum[:10])
```

or, more simply here, as `num` is empty before:

```
num = allnum[:10]
```

Note also that testing if each element is in the `num` list is quite slow. It's much faster to test if an element belongs to a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

So, you could use:

```
import random

allnum=[]
num=[]
for i in range(100):
    allnum.append(random.randint(1,99))

num = set(allnum[:10])
print (allnum)
print(num)

allnum = [i for i in allnum if i not in num]
print(allnum)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use set operations here as well to identify the difference between the two lists

```
import numpy as np
allnum = []
for i in range(100):
    allnum.append(np.random.randint(1,99))

# slice allnum to the desired level
num = allnum[:10]

# this is a good opportunity to use set operations and identify all elements in allnum that 
# are not in num
diff = list(set(allnum).difference(set(num)))
```

as an added bonus, set operations are blazing fast. You will however get only unique elements in your allnum list, so if a random number is generated multiple times, it will only appear once in the output.

And per the comment +1 you can do all of this using numpy in two lines:

```
arr1 = np.random.randint(1, 99, 100)
np.delete(arr1, arr1[:10])
```

Comment: when I tried using that an error came up: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/other/text.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: maybe it's the version of python I have?

Comment: @user9518577 That `numpy` isn't a built-in module, it's something you have to install separately. (Or use something like Anaconda or (x,y)-Python that comes with a bunch of scientific-stack stuff pre-installed.)

Comment: ohh sorry @abarnert

Comment: It's pretty strange to change the user's code to use numpy when everything you're doing with it is fighting against what numpy is good at. Appending to an array one by one is slower than appending to a list, and then you're converting an array to a set, etc., and never once doing anything with an array operation. So, why bring numpy into it?

Comment: You can use your regular random number generator

Comment: @abarnert its a good point - I just updated the example to demonstrate how the whole construct could be accomplished using numpy

Comment: Since you’re covering all the options, one more thing that might be worth adding: if the “no dups” thing isn’t acceptable, you can either (a) only convert the other list to a set, or (b) use collections.Counter as a multi set. (Both still retain the set performance benefits.)

Answer (score -1):

Just tried this and it worked.

```
first_list = list(range(5,15))
second_list = list(range(10,20))

first_minus_second = [x for x in first_list if x not in second_list]
```

Comment: yeah I tried that, but it didn't work because I had something else wrong, I'll probably change it to that now though, thanks